# LWT In cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I know the purpose of LWT in multinode that it locks the partition level data. 
I want to use a query like following,

```
INSERT INTO QUERY(a,b,c) values('av','bv','cv') IF NOT EXISTS
```

I Can't change this query for the single node and multi node setup, But when I run this query in single node it throws an error, Is there a way to hide the LWT or Handle the single node and multi node without changing the queries?

Also, Currently If am using two node and one node went down then I need to remove the IF NOT EXISTS from the query for insert and update ? How to design this, Could somebody help me?

Comment: hmmm - what error it gives you? I just checked on my single-node setup (DSE 5.1.5) - LWTs work just fine. What replication factor do you have? What write consistency?

Comment: that node got sanitized, I tried in a new single node and it is working fine for LWT queries. Alex, I will get back to this question once I face this issue again. If not I will close this shortly.

Comment: If it arise again, please add error message, and last lines from system.log & debug.log